# Perl to sum sliding windows of values in an array

Tags: arrays, perl, sum

I would like to create a moving window of sums from a tab-delimited array of data organized by the fourth column.  For simplicity, I replaced irrelevant fields with X and added the headers seen in the first row:

```
ID-Counts    X      X     Start    X      X     Locations      XXXX
 X-5000     [X]    [X]     0      [X]    [X]      1           [X...]
 X-26       [X]    [X]     1      [X]    [X]      1           [X...]
 X-34       [X]    [X]     1      [X]    [X]      0           [X...]
 X-3        [X]    [X]     20     [X]    [X]      9           [X...]
 X-200      [X]    [X]     30     [X]    [X]      0           [X...]
 X-1        [X]    [X]     40     [X]    [X]      5           [X...]
```

The first column contains a numeric ID and counts for that ID joined by a hyphen.  The fourth column contains all of the start sites that I would like to use to group the data.  The seventh column contains the number of locations that I need to normalize the counts by.

The overall value I would like to sum for each line is determined by splitting the counts from the ID and dividing them by the number of locations + 1 (for instance, the first row has a value of 2500, row 2 with 13, row three with 34).  Then I want to sum these counts/(locations+1) for every row that has a value in column four within 20units of each other, beginning at values 0-19, then 1-20, 2-21, etc. For example, window 0 (column four values ranging 0-19) would sum rows 1-3, window 1 would sum rows 2-4, window 2 would sum only row 4, and so forth.

My ideal output would then be two columns:  the first column has the beginning of the 20unit-window (0,1,2,...) and the second has the sum for each window (in the above data 2547, 47.3, etc).

I made a perl script that filters and organizes the data into this format and would like to add code for the summing across 20unit windows.  As a perl novice I would greatly appreciate any help and explanations.  I am familiar with split and arithmetic functions across columns but I am entirely lost on how to do these across moving windows in the array.  Thank you.

Comment: The important part is still unclear to me. Could you try to explain a little bit more about how to "sum across everything"?

Comment: Edited, hope it makes more sense.  Basically I want to search for values in column 4 within 20units of each other, sum their respective counts/loc+1 values, and do this for every 20unit grouping (Column 4 ranges 0-19, 1-20, 2-21...)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question well. What do you think about these implementations?

Solution 1: Write to the output file every time it reaches the unit-window (20).

```
#Assuming that you have an array of sums (@sums) and name of file ($filename)
my $window_no  = 20;
my $window_sum = 0;
my @window_nos = ();

for (my $i = 1; $i <= $#sums; $i++) {
    push (@window_nos, $i);
    if ( i % window_no == 0 ) {
        write_file($filename, join(',', @window_nos) . "\t" . $window_sum . "\n");
        $window_sum = 0;
        @window_nos = ();
    }
}


if (scalar @window_nos > 1) {
    write_file($filename, join(',', @window_nos) . "\t" . $window_sum) . "\n");
}
```

Solution 2: Append values to a scalar variable and use that to write once to the output file.

```
#Assuming that you have an array of sums (@sums) and name of file ($filename)
my $window_no     = 20;
my $window_sum    = 0;
my @window_nos    = ();
my $file_contents = '';

for (my $i = 1; $i <= $#sums; $i++) {
    push (@window_nos, $i);
    if (i % window_no == 0) {            
        $file_contents .= join(',', @window_nos) . "\t" . $window_sum . "\n";
        $window_sum = 0;
        @window_nos = ();
    }
}

if (scalar @window_nos > 1) {
    $file_contents .= join(',', @window_nos) . "\t" . $window_sum . "\n";
}

write_file($filename, $file_contents);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following code to see if it does what you want.
Could probably be optimized somewhat, but I basically did a brute force search for all starts within a 20 unit window above the current Start.
Ken

Output:

```
0-19:  2547.000000
1-20:  47.300000
20-39:  200.300000
30-49:  200.166667
40-59:  0.166667
```

Code

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#  Hash indexed by Start
#  Each value contains the sum of all ( Counts/Locations+1 ) for
#     this Start value
my %sum;

while (<DATA>)
{
    #  ignore comments
    next if /^\s*#/;
    my ( $id_count,undef,undef,$start,undef,undef,$numLocations ) = 
       split ' ';
    my ($id,$count) = split '-',$id_count;
    $sum{$start} += $count / ( $numLocations + 1 );
}  

foreach my $start ( sort keys %sum )
{
   my $totalSum = 0;
   #  Could probably be optimized.
   foreach my $start2 ( $start .. $start+19 )
   {
      $totalSum += $sum{$start2} if defined($sum{$start2});      
   }
   printf "%d-%d:  %f\n", $start, $start+19, $totalSum;
}

__DATA__
#ID-Counts    X      X     Start    X      X     Locations      XXXX
 X-5000     [X]    [X]     0      [X]    [X]      1           [X...]
 X-26       [X]    [X]     1      [X]    [X]      1           [X...]
 X-34       [X]    [X]     1      [X]    [X]      0           [X...]
 X-3        [X]    [X]     20     [X]    [X]      9           [X...]
 X-200      [X]    [X]     30     [X]    [X]      0           [X...]
 X-1        [X]    [X]     40     [X]    [X]      5           [X...]
```

Comment: Several problems in this code. Not sure where I copied this from. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %sum_for;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {

    if ( $line !~ m{\A [#] }xms ) {

        $line =~ s{\A \s* ( [^-]+ ) - }{$1 }xms;    # separate the ID

        my @columns = split /\s+/, $line;    # assumes no space in values

        my $count = $columns[1];
        my $start = $columns[4];
        my $locat = $columns[7] + 1;

        $sum_for{$start} += $count / $locat;
    }
}

print Dumper( \%sum_for );

my @start_ranges;
{
    my ($max_start) = sort { $b <=> $a } keys %sum_for;

    # max => range count
    #  10 => 1
    #  20 => 2
    #  30 => 2
    #  40 => 3
    #  50 => 3
    #  ...
    my $range_count = $max_start / 20;

    push @start_ranges, [ 0, 19 ];

    for ( 1 .. $range_count ) {

        push @start_ranges, [ map { $_ + 20 } @{ $start_ranges[-1] } ];
    }
}

my %total_for;

for my $range_ra (@start_ranges) {

    my $range_key = sprintf '%d-%d', @{$range_ra};

    for my $start ( $range_ra->[0] .. $range_ra->[1] ) {

        if ( exists $sum_for{$start} ) {

            $total_for{$range_key} += $sum_for{$start};
        }
    }
}

print Dumper( \%total_for );

__DATA__
#ID-Counts    X      X     Start    X      X     Locations      XXXX
 X-5000     [X]    [X]     0      [X]    [X]      1           [X...]
 X-26       [X]    [X]     1      [X]    [X]      1           [X...]
 X-34       [X]    [X]     1      [X]    [X]      0           [X...]
 X-3        [X]    [X]     20     [X]    [X]      9           [X...]
 X-200      [X]    [X]     30     [X]    [X]      0           [X...]
 X-1        [X]    [X]     40     [X]    [X]      5           [X...]
```

The output comes out like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => 47,
          '40' => '0.166666666666667',
          '0' => 2500,
          '30' => 200,
          '20' => '0.3'
        };
$VAR1 = {
          '40-59' => '0.166666666666667',
          '20-39' => '200.3',
          '0-19' => 2547
        };
```

The bit on computing the start ranges took a little pondering.
Thanks for the interesting question.